# Comparing Each Element with next element to see if it's in a range of 80

Tags: python, arrays

I have a .csv file of 2289 datapoints, with the first ten being :

[1071936.0,
1231944.0,
1391953.0,
1551957.0,
1711960.0,
1711961.0,
1871964.0,
2031968.0,
2031969.0,
2191973.0]

On row 5 and 6, there are two data points who are only 1 data point away from each other. Since the array is sorted from smallest to largest, I want to see if element X and element X +1 are within 80 data points of each other. If they are, then remove element X + 1.

```
n = 0
y = []
for k in range(10):
    y = duplicates_removed_tr_sc
    window = duplicates_removed_tr_sc[n]
    for x in range(80):
        if(duplicates_removed_tr_sc[k]== duplicates_removed_tr_sc[n]):
            del y[k+1] #delete the k+1 element if it is 
            window = window + 1
y = np.asarray(y)
y = sorted(y)
```

This is what I tried but it's not giving me a valid outcome :/ would appreciate any help!

Comment: Where are you checking if they're within 80 of each other? You're only checking for exact duplicates, not `array[n+1] < array[n]+80`

Comment: Write a generator. Only yield the current element, if the previous element is at least the min distance away. Alternatively, if you insist on loops with arrays, make one that copies all "good" elements from one array to a new one. Don't try to modify the array you're iterating over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always best to create a NEW list with the data you want to keep.

```
keep = []
last = -9999
for value in datapoints:
    if value - last > 80:
        keep.append(value)
    last = value
keep = np.asarray(keep)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution was also a lot faster than my for loops.